# Get Average session time for Single activity application

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using Google analytics version V2 in my application.My aim is to get average time user spends on each activity,I successfully able to fetch session time of the application which have more than one activity,but I am struggling to get results on Single Activity Application.

Average session time is displayed on Google Analytic dashboard.In case of single activity session time is always displayed as 0 seconds.I am using `EasyTracker`.

Below is my dashboard screenshot.[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. any luck on by now?

Comment: Can you please explain more about the activities on your app?